# Loading entry based on dynamic route

Tags: routes, descendantof

I'm trying to load an entry based on the following url:

```
/artists/nameOfArtist/nameOfCategory/myEntry/thumb
```

This URL follows the structure of my entries: Artist > Category > Entry

So, I'm thinking that something like this should work:

```
{% set project = craft.request.getSegment(-2) %}
```

- This gets me the variable from 'myEntry' segment.

```
{% set artistParent = craft.request.getSegment(-4) %}
```

- This gets me the variable from 'nameOfArtist' segment.

Then, I want to find the 'project' entry that lives under 'nameOfArtist'.

```
{% set entry = craft.entries.slug(project).descendantOf(artistParent).first %}
```

but this is not working. What am I missing? Or is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: I take it the section is a structure (not a channel) called "Artists"? And the category is a `category` and not just another structure entry?

Comment: Both, Artist and Category are structure entries. Category is child of Artist.

Comment: Ok cool, then does my answer below work for you?

Comment: @Ryan I still need to figure this out. Will post an update.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's because you're trying to cram too much into your `entry` variable.  For one, [`.slug()`](https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/craft.entries#slug) is going to return an entry with that slug, so I think that's a bit of a full stop.  For two, [`.descendantOf()`](https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/craft.entries#descendantOf) accepts an EntryModal object, but you're feeding it a uri/slug (ie. `name-of-artist`).

Try something like this:

```
{% set artistEntry = craft.entries.slug(artistParent).first %}
{% set projectEntry = craft.entries.descendantOf(artistEntry).first %}
```

Keep in mind that `.descendantOf()` only works with structures (not channels), so I'm assuming that's what you're working with. Also, you may need to specify how far down the lineage to go with [`.descendantDist()`](https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/craft.entries#descendantDist).